# My C Code exe only runs on my PC. How do I Include VCRuntime140.dll in my C code exe

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, reference, exe

I have recently been getting in C code.

I would like to create a stand alone .exe that can run on a windows PC.
The exe runs on my pc, of course because of the installation. However, on another PC I get an error

**> code execution cannot proceed because vcruntime140d.dll was not found**

How do I include this dll so that it will run on any PC

Any assistance will be fantastic.

Its a very simple code, see below

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("\n\nHi there.\n\nThis is a .exe test.\n\n If you are seeing this, it is successful.\n\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

I have googled this for a couple of days now, there has not been a real answer to my question.

EDIT after last comment
Here are the settings I have adjusted
I did select x64

[image: Advanced Settings]

[image: Code Generation Settings]

Comment: I would guess that you built the executable using dynamic linking. You need to use static linking. How to do that in MSVC, I don't remember.

Comment: Your question title contradicts the text in the body of your question. In the title, you are referring to `VCRuntime140.dll`, whereas in the question body, you are referring to `vcruntime140d.dll`. Note the additional `d` at the end of the file name. This detail is important, because the `d` probably stands for "debug", indicating it is the debug version of the DLL. Therefore, in the question title, you are claiming that you are using the non-debug version of the DLL, but in the question text, you are claiming that you are using the debug version of the DLL. Please clarify this contradiction.

Comment: The distinction mentioned in my previous comment is important, because it is common for non-developer PCs to only have the non-debug ("release") versions of DLLs installed.

Comment: When you create a new project in Microsoft Visual Studio, it generally creates two configurations for you named "Debug" and "Release". If you want the executable file that you create to be runnable on other computers that do not have the debug versions of the DLLs installed, you should select the "Release" configuration before starting the build process. That way, your program will link with the non-debug versions of the DLLs. This also has the advantage that compiler optimizations will be active, so that the code will run faster.

Comment: Thank you so much for the input. I did change the properties to "Release" I am going to test it on another PC.  And thank you for the "d" info.   I will do the test and let you know.

Comment: Does the Runtime library make a difference?  Multithreaded DLL /MD or Multithreaded /MT

Comment: @GarethSwemmer: "Multithreaded DLL" requires that the user [have the (non-debug) DLL installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170), whereas "Multithreaded" will put all necessary code into the `.exe` file itself, so you don't require an external DLL for the runtime library. However, this will increase the size of the executable.

Comment: Thanks so much. I don't mind the exe size. I have changed it, and now the same error for 'ucrtbased.dll'.   Also a "d".

Comment: I have added the screen shots of the settings currently after the above suggestions.